# calling object.width is returning NaN in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, width, collision, createjs

I am currently working on a game that has to do with a rocket ship moving around and objects(circles) are falling from the top. The goal of this game is to not hit the objects as they are falling down the screen. I am running into problems when writing my collision algorithm.

I have declared var hit = false; at the top of my code
I have also put all of the circles into an array called projectiles.

I believe that I have the logic correct but I discovered that when calling either p.width or ship.width it returns NaN. I have tried using offsetWidth and that didn't work either. I am wondering how else to go about getting the width of my objects

The else statement at the bottom is just to check if .width is returning the correct number. Once I get it to work it will be removed and replaced with the final parts of the collision algorithm.

```
function checkCollision()
{

    for (i = 0; i < projectiles.length; i++) {
        var p = projectiles[i];
        if((p.x + p.width) < ship.x)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if(p.x > (ship.x + ship.width))
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if(p.y > (ship.y + ship.height))
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else if((p.y + p.height) < ship.y)
        {
            hit = false;
        }
        else {
            console.log(ship.x + ship.width);
        }
```

Comment: What is `ship`???

Comment: Well I think the problem is in `.x` and `.y` not `.width` and `.height`!

Comment: What is the value of `ship` and how is it defined? It's not just "an image", it's a JavaScript object. Provide more detail.

Comment: if I were to just use console.log(ship.x) or console.log(p.x) it will display the correct x values as they should be in the console

Comment: queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    queue.addEventListener("complete", init);
    queue.loadManifest([{ id: "ship", src: "ship.png" }]);

Comment: function buildShip()
{
    var image = queue.getResult("ship");
    ship = new createjs.Bitmap(image);
    ship.nextX = 0;
    ship.x = SHIPX0; ship.y = SHIPY0;
    stage.addChild(ship);
    stage.update();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation for [`createjs.Bitmap`](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Bitmap.html) there do not exist properties for `.width` and `.height`. Instead access it's [`.image (HTMLImageElement)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) property which have defined width and height properties: `ship.image.width` and `ship.image.height`.

Comment: I am still having problems with getting the projectile values. when calling p.x it is returning 0 everytime and p.width returns NaN

Comment: Are `p` the same type as `ship`? If so use `p.image.width` as well, in terms of why `p.x` is zero may need to be a separate question as there isn't any information provided on updating your projectile array. For new questions add a new post on SO, instead of un-accepting my answer...

Answer (score 0):

If your object is an EaselJS Bitmap, you can retrieve the physical size using `getBounds()`. This method works for *some* EaselJS display objects (ie, not Shapes, and accuracy varies with Text).

```
var bounds = ship.getBounds();
var w = bounds.width;
```

Notes:

- per @Spencer's message, you can access the `.image`, and get the width/height, but it will be the original size of the image, so if you transform the bitmap instance, or any of the parent containers, the value will be wrong. The `getBounds` will consider the scale transformation (if it exists)
- values may not be correct if the item is rotated.
- bounds are based on the registration point, so the x/y might be non-zero.
- You will get 0 for width/height if the image is not yet loaded

For your projectile, if it is a shape, the bounds will always be null, but you can manually set them if you know them, and they will be properly calculated/transformed:

```
var p = new createjs.Shape();
p.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0,0,20);
p.setBounds(new createjs.Rectangle(-20,-20,40,40));
```

Here is some info on why there is no `.width` or `.height`: http://blog.createjs.com/update-width-height-in-easeljs/